# android en otro país

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en androide cuando lo instalo me funciona normal todo bien el problema es cuando lo instalo en un dispositivo androide que esta en otro país me sale lamentablemente, la aplicación se detuvo  .

Comment: ¿en los paises que has probado has usado el mismo dispositivo? ¿Estas seguro que el problema no es otro?, ¿Has revisado el log?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base al documento [ask] para que obtengas la ayuda requerida en el sitio, te sugerimos editar tu pregunta, **¿Que error se muestra en la consola Firebase - Crashlytics?**. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos!

Comment: deberias subir el logcat o ver cual es el error y postearlo